# Getting inverted commas appended in request while reading from csv in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0

I was trying to read csv file using csvdata config element in jmeter so as to test multiple logins but when I try to read the value from csv file then I get inverted commas appended with respect to result. Please tell me how to get rid of these commas being passed in the request parameters

Please find my csv data config and excel file and request parameter screenshot in attachments

[image: Excel file image]

[image: CSV data config image]

[image: Error image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter normally doesn't add anything to the variables, most probably you have the quotation marks in the generated CSV file, open it with normal text editor like [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Notepad) and use find-and-replace feature to remove the quotation marks from there.

---

If you cannot efficiently control the CSV data you can use [__strReplace() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplacesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup) in order to remove the quotation marks from the variables originating from the CSV Data Set Config on the fly like:

```
${__strReplace(${Username},\",,)}
```

Demo:

[image]

You can install `__strReplace()` function as well as other [Custom JMeter Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/) using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image]

Comment: I opened it using notepad and commas were there so I removed them and ran the csv again using csv datconfig but still I am getting error and login is not happening

Comment: I opened it using notepad and commas were there so I removed them and ran the csv again using csv datconfig but still I am getting error and login is not happening please refer links for screenshots of request image and response image which I got. Request image link:- https://pasteboard.co/HNZGBH1.png and response image link:- https://pasteboard.co/HNZH9G6.png

Comment: I see you have the same `_csrf_token` value in all requests. It should not happen, this parameter needs to be dynamic, i.e. you need to extract it from the previous response using suitable [JMeter Post-Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), convert it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and replace the recorded value with the variable. Check out [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) article for more details.

Comment: I tried by using Post processor in homepage request which executes just before login HTTP request gave regular expression for csrf token and converted csrf token into variable but still it is giving error "Csrf token failed" , please refer image for Regular expression post processor :-https://pasteboard.co/HO9WP3D.png and parameterization done in HTTP request :- https://pasteboard.co/HO9Xcnu.png and the request which is sent :- https://pasteboard.co/HO9XDaZ.png and the Response received which contains "Cssrf token authentication failed" message :- https://pasteboard.co/HO9Y6X8.png

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I opened a csv file as a normal text file, I saw a `Values, value2`.

After removing it, it started working as expected.